# Whats the new size of fb page tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**we known fb launches timeline pages**

whats the width of fb tab app of timeline pages?

do you known the actual width or/and any offical guide which shows the width of app for timeline pages

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You can adjust the width of an app on your Page to be Narrow (520px) or Wide (810px)."

http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=295605743827115

Comment: do you mean the default page tab apps like Photos, Notes, etc? Otherwise, I am pretty sure that page tab and page app are the same thing.

Comment: If you go to http://developers.facebook.com/ and select Apps, click Edit settings (of any app), scroll down, click "Page Tab", you will see the option to change "Page Tab Width".